# Building mac app generates .app in a .app

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm trying to port my game to SDL on the mac. I have already got it working on iOS so I thought let's also try OSX.

So I've got it running in xCode. 
However when I archive, I end up with an .app package, and if I open it it contains Contents and in it MacOs, plist, etc
however, it also contains the same .app again, and when I look in the contents, it contains the same folders.
To make it weirder, the inner app I can run, the outer app just crashes (it can't find embedded frameworks).
This is in fact correct since the outer app doesn't contain a framework folder, but the inner one does. (I embed the frameworks with a copy files step)

What can cause an App in an App?  And how can I fix it?

[image]

The image shows the contents of the app (framebuffertest) and in it the exact same app (and same folders) again

Answer (score 0):

So solved for now.

turns out that if you do 'Export app' (from the archiving options (Xcode 9)) than you'll end up with an app in an app.

But when you chose 'Development' export option, then you just end up with the inner .app which works fine.